# How to automatically keep a user signed in a React and Loopback app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, loopback

I have created an app which requires the user to log in to access a bunch of stuff using Loopback and React.
The folder structure right now is all of the React stuff is in it's own folder, `client/` while all the server side is just in the root folder of the project.

This what my code looks like whenever I get the user to log in:

```
export default function authenticate (email, password) {

  return axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/users/login', { email, password })
    .then(res => {
      const token = res.data.id
      localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token)
      return res
    })
}
```

It may be also important to note that I am using Redux to check is the user is logged in throughout the app. I set a state called `loggedInUser` in my store, which keeps track of the user object with all the data I need. This is the code I run whenever I click the login form's button:

```
  handleSignInButton (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()

    const { email, password } = this.state

    authenticate(email, password) // this calls the function from above
    .then(user => {
      this.props.logInUser(user.data) // sets my redux state as the user which just logged in
    })
  }
```

That is all fine and dandy for when I actually log in through my login component, but the question is if I, for example hard refresh, or leave the page then come back, my state becomes the default and I don't know how I can recover my user without going through the whole logging in form all over again.

What is the best way to do this? How can I find out which user is logged in when I already have a token set?

Comment: Since you are using a jwtToken, you should check the localStorage for the token, validate it and update your state if valid. You can then skip the login page and put them straight in. If the token is invalid or timed out, show the login page.

Comment: But how do I know just by checking the token which user is logged in so I can set him as the loggedInUser redux state?

Comment: You need to take he stored jwtToken, send it back to the server for validation, and if it is valid, let them in, if not, give them the login page. Assuming you aren't offline and have a good web connection this "should" be quick. The other option is to assume the token is valid since you put it in to the local cache, let them in while verifying, and if the verification turns out to be false or timed out, show them the login screen.

Comment: From my understanding, this still doesn't give me the user object.
Furthermore, how can I validate this token?